# sql same column value for all rows and update it frequently

Tags: sql, triggers, insert-update, calculated-columns

What I want to achieve:
I have a table denoting ID and Credits of each individual ID.
I want to rate each ID as, `rate(ID)=Credit(ID)/sum(Credit(ID))` the sum is over all IDs
I will be updating the table quite frequently and want to keep the `sum(Credit(ID))` handy by creating another column and storing this sum in the table (say `sigmaID`), which **should always have exact same value for all rows**.
Whenever I change Credit for an ID (say add 100), I can simply do the same operation on this column value (add 100)

- Do I have to update `sigmaID` for all rows? Will it be efficient?
- I would like to periodically check if `sigmaID` is indeed `sum(Credit(ID))` for consistency , am I overdoing it? Will it inefficient?
- Is there any other approach to this (I am worried about efficiency)?

Kindly provide pure SQL queries as I need to *put all of this in an `UPDATE` trigger* which will calculate this rating (and loads of other formulas with other parameters of ID). I may have access to scripting language (PHP/python) but I don't know for sure. Hence the pure SQL request.

Comment: My experience doesn't allow me to speak with authority, but it seems likely that you could achieve your goal by using a scalar [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189593.aspx) to calculate the sum and a persisted [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) to assign the result to.

Comment: @andriy-m : thanks for the links, the computed column stuff looks promising, is it restricted to MSSQL only or can I use it in mysql/other sql ??

Comment: Can't say whether the feature is restricted to SQL Server only, but [this source](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/51-Cross-Compare-of-SQL-Server,-MySQL,-and-PostgreSQL.html) reveals, that at least two particular server products, MySQL and PostgreSQL, *do not* have support for computed columns (or, rather, they didn't at the time).

Comment: @andriy-m thanks, i think i will rework my strategy or ask on stackexchange for db admins.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my English is very very poor.

As i realized, you want to have all information about your column values, in past and present?

You want to log it ? If it so you can make journal table and log everything yo want in it by trigger.

best regards,

tato mumladze

Comment: No, I want to add all values of column Credit, and update this value every time Credit value of any row changes.

Comment: ok, than u can do so:

'code'
create or replace trigger [yourtrigger]
after update of [yourcollumn] on [yourtable]
for each row

begin
update [yourtable]
set [yourcollumn] = [yourvalue]
where [yourcollumn] = [whatyouwant];

end [yourtrigger];